# Concatenate multiple arraylists references

Tags: java, arraylist, reference

So I have 3 arraylists called for example `books`, `newspapers`, `magazines` and one arraylist called `resources`.

If you do something like : `resources = books;` then resources will point to the same memory location as books.

But how can you add to this `resources` at the end the start of the other two arraylists so the resources will contain all arraylists? Something like concatenation of arraylists memories references.

Comment: You really can't glue together different types unless they share a common ancestory, if newspaper is not the same type as books.

Comment: Can you share some coding that How u initialize your arraylists...

Comment: `ArrayList<Resource> books = new ArrayList();

   ArrayList<Resource> magazines = new ArrayList();


   ArrayList<Resource> newspapers = new ArrayList();`

Actually I have an abstract class called `Resource` and three extended classes `Book`, `Newspaper`, `Magazine`. I need an efficient way to iterate through all arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want the elements of book, newspaper and magazine `ArrayLists` will appear in one `ArrayList` `resources`, then you can make use of   `ArrayList.addAll(Collection)` function: Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator.

   ```
   resources.addAll(book);
   resources.addAll(newspaper);
   resource.addAll(magazine);
   ```
2. You want to create an `ArrayList` which will contain the ArrayLists as element:

   ```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>resources = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.add(book);
    resources.add(newspaper);
    resources.add(magazine);
   ```

Assumed that the type of book, magazine and newspaper `ArrayLists` is `ArrayList<String>`. However, if second one is your target then i think it is better you declare resources as an `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>resources = new HashMap<>();
            // replace String with the type of the elements of book\newspaper\magazine
    resources.put("book", book);
    resources.put("newspaper", newspaper);
    resources.put("magazine", magazine);
```

Comment: This way I will consume memory unnecessary.

Comment: which way ? I have mentioned three ways, i think. And i don't see any one of this will consume memory unnecessarily, at the very least last two, because they will save your array List as element with same reference. Anything you change to outer array list, for example `book`, it will be reflected on the ArrayList book added to resources or the HashMap implementation. Give the last two some try