# Adding one arraylist to another

Tags: java, android, arrays, list

Here are my two Arraylists and how do I add one to the other

```
private ArrayList<String>  myStringList= new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String>  newStringList= new ArrayList<String>();
```

I would like to add all the strings which are in `myStringList` to `newStringList`.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate multiple arraylists references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021410/concatenate-multiple-arraylists-references)

Comment: did you just ask this duplicate question to answer it for yourself?

Comment: @Kevin. Not really :) but found lately the mistake I have done and finally answered my own question here so that someone might go through it.

Comment: @coder ok, it just looks confusing since the question and the answer are just 1 minute apart from each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

Here is the way:

```
 myStringList.addAll(newStringList);
```

Comment: @Lathy- Please check the answered duration of mine and his. He has mentioned after I have done that :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the constructor which takes a [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) like

```
private List<String>  newStringList= new ArrayList<>(myStringList);
```

Or call [`List.addAll(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) like

```
newStringList.addAll(myStringList);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.Hope it helps

```
1. myStringList.addAll(newStringList);
2. you can loop and add to other.
```